# how to specify a generic data type that extends from a specific class

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, generic-collections

I am new kotlin, and I would like to know how provide a generic data type to a method as aparameter. in java

```
methods(<? extends Class1>)
```

please have a look at the code posted below and let me know how to refactor it to accommodate the provided comment.

**update**

```
   var fragTransactionInstance = getFragmentManagerInstance()?.let {
        it.getFragmentTransactionInstance()
            ?.replaceTransaction(R.id.fragLeft, fragmentLeft)//RequiredTypeVariable (T)Found: FragmentLeft
            ?.replaceTransaction(R.id.fragRight, fragmentRight)
    }?.also {
        it.commit()
    }
```

**code**:

```
 fun FragmentTransaction.replaceTransaction(layout: Int, fragment : Fragment): FragmentTransaction {
    return this.replace(layout, fragment)
}
//the second parameter must be any parameter that extends Fragment. e.g: <? extends Fragment>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out solution below to create functions with generics in Kotlin :

```
fun <T : SomeClass> someFun(t: T) {

}
```

In your case, it would be like :

```
fun <T : Fragment> FragmentTransaction.replaceTransaction(layout: Int, t: T): FragmentTransaction {
    return this.replace(layout, t)
}
```

Here, **t** should be of type `Fragment`.

Refer **[here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html)** for more info.

Comment: please have a look at the update section added above...i modified the code as you .suggested ..however, i received the error stated in the update section

Comment: What is the **fragmentLeft** and **fragementRight** in your case?